# PrimeFaces 4.0 premium theme compatibility

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-extensions

Is PrimeFaces 4.x compatible with theme Ecuador or any premium theme ?
or i have to migrate my project to a specific version ,
please advise me before buying any theme
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PF 4 is very old and you should DEFINITELY consider updating just for security reasons alone.  It looks like most Premium Themes are compatible with PF 5 or PF 6+ from this blog post on PrimeFaces site.

https://www.primefaces.org/premium-layouts-and-themes-updated/

> This update cycle brings compatibility with PrimeFaces 6.0, due to a
>   resource optimization in PF6, the menus of layouts were broken. We’ve
>   added the fix in a way that same layout can both work with 6.0 and
>   also 5.x. with version detection.

But once again I cannot recommend enough upgrading to PF 6.2 if possible to get the benefits of all the latest browser fixes and security fixes.